# Best solution for sending requests through proxy

Tags: php, proxy

I need to make ~ 525 requests daily, but I must use Proxy IP. I tried using various ip's from Proxy servers list's and it didn't work at all. It always breaks at some point, hence I don't have all the data I need. Is it possible to buy/rent a private proxy ip, if not what's the best option? Thanks

Comment: What purpose is the proxy IP serving? Since I'd usually get my own server for this purpose.

Comment: It's up to my boss